# Rust: returning result from module function: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 0

Tags: rust

I don't understand, what the compiler wants me to change.

I have this module:

src/app.rs

```
extern crate actix_web;
use actix_web::{App};

pub fn create() -> Result<App, Error> {
  let app = App::new();
  Ok(app)
}
```

What I keep getting from the compiler is:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 0

7 | pub fn create() -> Result<App, Error> {
                              ^^^ expected 2 type arguments
```

How is <App, Error> not two type arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.1.0/actix_web/struct.App.html), the `App` is generic over two types as well. Your return type should look something like this: `Result<App<T, B>, Error>`. Consult the documentation to find out the specifics.

Comment: I totally missed that the app instance's return enum has two variants too. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That's not about enum variants. That's about type parameters, which are not directly connected to the enum variants in general case.